# How to reorder bootstrap columns based on mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen there are some examples of using push/pull with bootstrap 3 but I haven't had much like trying it out. Is it possible in this example to get `col-sm-4` content to show before col-`sm-5 col-lg-12` on mobile as `col-sm-4`is currently showing last on mobile.

```
<section id="inner-page" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-7">
            <div class="post-media">
                <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mTop-20">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-12">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Bootstrap 3**

You can use `push` and `pull` classes

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div style="border: 1px solid red" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-push-8 col-sm-push-7">
      content
   </div>
   <div style="border: 1px solid green" class="col-lg-8 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-4">
      <div class="post-media">
            <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
               <ul class="slides">
                  <li></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
               <ul class="slides">
                  <li></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mTop-20">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-12">
               content
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**With Bootstrap 5**

You can use the order property

- add the class `order-0 order-sm-2` for `col-sm-4` and the classe `order-1` for `col-sm-7`

or the flex-direction property

- add the classes `flex-column-reverse flex-sm-row` for the row

Comment: Using the `flex-column-reverse flex-sm-row` approach is the easiest solution for Bootstrap 5. Worked a treat.